# Unable to calculate limit with Mathematica but WolframAlpha

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For expression in Mathematica

```
   Limit[(x^2 - xy)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y]) , {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

I get the result `Indeterminate`.
But in WolframAlpha, I can get the correct result 0.

Is there's a way to get the limit from Mathematica?

Comment: You should put a space between ``x`` and ``y`` when multiplying, otherwise Mathematica thinks this is some other variable ``xy``.

Comment: And with @Domen's fix, the result is calculated correctly.

Comment: /facepalm @Domen you're right, I should put a space between two variables or using `\[Times\]`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 - x y)/(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[y])

Limit[f[r Cos[a], r Sin[a]], r -> 0]

(*0*)
```

Comment: I get correct result even without ``Cos`` and ``Sin`` – there was a missing space in author's code.

Comment: @Domen Not in my version (MA11.1)

Comment: @yarrchik, oh, okay, I am using 12.3.

Comment: Multivariate limits came in V11.2. Note that the polar coordinate trick fails on some limits that do not exist (e.g. `f[x_, y_] := x^2 y/(x^4 + y^2)`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 In your example it is sufficient to parametrize the path differently, like `Limit[f[r Cos[a], r^2 Sin[a]], r -> 0]`. As usual in mathematics, one needs to be careful about the details. I am quite sure one can even find an example where the limit along any path is the same, but the double one does not exists. The Moore-Osgood theorem should be used.

Answer (score 0):

As @Domen mentioned, there should be a space between variable `xy` or using `\[Times]` symbol to make Mathematica understand my input correctly.